# Java is Pass-By-Value and Pass-By-Reference Both

Tags: java, pass-by-value

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Java pass by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

Let me know the answer soon Please!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java pass by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference) and many of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+pass+by+value

Comment: We are letting you know the answer.

Comment: If you want a fast answer, why not search for it? http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=java+pass+by+value 23,400,000 hits!

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't pass method arguments by reference - it passes them by value.

Comment: +1, with the comment that *references* are passed *by value*.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html

Answer (score -5):

The Java compiler decides what's best.

Comment: What do you mean by that? The Java compiler emits *Java bytecode* and *Java bytecode* has rules governing this. I don't think the compiler has a choice in the matter.